# problem only occuring when accessing site through VPN

Tags: xml

This site uses JS/XML/XSLT, and it works with no errors in chrome/safari/FF/IE8/IE7, when accessed remotely, but if I access the site through a VPN, I get an error that either a document element is lacking, or the XML is not well-formed, which it is. But this only happens with IE7 - the main browser we need working unfortunately.

Perhaps the client did something locally? but the xml/xsl files dont seem to be modified. I'm tearing my hair out over this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried all the obvious stuff? check the URL is the same, clear the cache, and use something like [xmlverbatim](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/) to see what document the webpage is transforming, it could be using a different one than you think it's using somehow.